# Is there a refactoring pattern to avoid infinite re-renders due to identic data perpetually jumping between parent to child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, refactoring, web-frontend

Imagine a simple part of a React application that consists of `OuterComponent` and `InnerComponent` inside of it. There are instructions these components must follow:

- Whenever the `data` in `OuterComponent` changes its value, it must overwrite `InnerComponent`'s `localData`'s current value.
- Whenever the `localData` in `InnerComponent` changes its value, it must overwrite `OuterComponent`'s `data`'s current value.

Here is the code in question:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const InnerComponent = ({ data = [], onChange = null }) => {
  const [localData, setLocalData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (onChange) onChange(localData);
  }, [localData, onChange]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("render");
    setLocalData(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      {localData.map((e) => (
        <div>{e}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const OuterComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(["alice", "bob"]);

  return <InnerComponent data={data} onChange={setData} />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <OuterComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since this situation is something which can arise in a lot of cases and thus is typical, are there any existing time-honored ways of refactoring that code into something free from potential infinite rendering cases? I'm also curious whether there is a way if `localData` is an array while `data` is an object that has this array in one of its keys which should be monitored by a child component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in such cases I'd keep a ref of the previous localData in the InnerComponent and add a guard clause, in the useEffect that calls onChange, to test against current localData e.g.:

```js
const prevLocalData = useRef(localData);
useEffect(() => {
  if (JSON.stringify(localData) === JSON.stringify(prevLocalData.current)) {
    return undefined;
  }

  onChange(localData);
}, [localData, onChange])
```

Comment: Why use `JSON.stringify`? For example, `lodash` has `isEqual` function that does a deep comparison whether the _contents_ of objects are equal.